# Rewrite Rule Not Redirecting To The Specified File

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Recently I started working with .htaccess file to redirect API call to a specific file. However, even though my .htaccess file is working (tested it with just text on top of the file and I get "Internal Server Error") my rule is not working. Instead, Index.php is always read. The goal is, whenever the url ends with "myOwnAPI/" it takes you to the file "somefile.php". All files(index.php, somefile.php, .htaccess) leave in the same directory.

The .htaccess file contains just one rule.

Please help.

httpd.conf file

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride All
    Require all denied
</Directory>

AllowOverride All
```

.htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule   ^myOwnAPI/?$   somefile.php  [NC,L]
```

Comment: Could you please do let us know what link you are hitting which you are expecting to be served by somefile.php?(samples of url will help). Then please do mention if your somefile.php is present in same directory where htaccess is present?

Comment: I am using post man for testing. The url is localhost/myOwnAPI/. And yes, as mentioned in my question both file are in the same directory.

Comment: I don't have postman with me, if you have curl you can run this `curl -IL "http://localhost:80//myOwnAPI/"` once and see what it does?

Comment: You do  not have to have postman. When making the request in the web browser it is the same.

Comment: I agree but curl will give you more information on what's happening etc I believe so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every url start with a "/" so

```
RewriteRule   ^myOwnAPI/?$   somefile.php  [NC,L]
```

won't ever match.
Change it to

```
RewriteRule   ^/myOwnAPI/?   /somefile.php  [NC,L]
```

Moreover, please read the offical documentation https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html if you need to "pass" the parameters to the new url (flag QSA).